# What Is Wrong With This FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, xml

I can't seem to figure out why this won't work in MS SQL Server. It seems to not group the lines. Specifically I see:

1036    SC

1036    S1

1094    VO

1094    V1

1094    V2

When I expect to see:

1036    SC,S1

1094    VO,V1,V2

Can someone see something wrong with the syntax?

```
SELECT DISTINCT oa.acct_cd AS [Account], 
                STUFF((SELECT ',' + CASE WHEN o.trans_type like 'BUY%' then 'buy of ' else 'sell of ' end + s.ticker AS [text()]
                       FROM [dbo].[synCRtblTS_ORDER] o INNER JOIN [dbo].[synCRtblCSM_SECURITY] s 
                       ON o.SEC_ID = s.SEC_ID
                       WHERE o.ORDER_ID = oa.ORDER_ID AND o.status IN ('OPEN','WORK','PENDING')
                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [buy/sell]
FROM [dbo].[synCRtblTS_ORDER_ALLOC] oa INNER JOIN tblPortfolio p
ON oa.ACCT_CD = p.Account INNER JOIN tblInvestmentObjective io
ON io.Code = p.InvestmentObjective
WHERE p.AsOfDate = (SELECT AsOfDate FROM tblDateAsOf) and io.CashMgmtStrategy IN ('SC','VO')
GROUP BY oa.ORDER_ID, oa.acct_cd
order by 1
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Some product specific SQL there...)

Comment: Maybe remove oa.ORDER_ID from the GROUP BY?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific than *"won't work"*, do you get an error? If so post the error message. Do you get unexpected results? If so post some sample data, the results you are getting and the results you are expecting. As it stands this question is an exercise in mind reading, not debugging!

Comment: It's harder for other people as we cannot run the query. Could you at least post what the error message is?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited this to be more specific. Also I cannot not remove anything from the group by otherwise I get the aggregate function error.

Answer (score 0):

The Information you give is not enough... Within your STUFF you create (and concatenate) string which should contain "buy of" or "sell of". You are missing this information in your output.

It's guessing that your SC, S1, VO values are CashMgmtStrategy entries. You are not concatenating them...

Without deeper knowledge of your tables I cannot solve your problem, but here you'll find a working example of concatenation via `FOR XML` and `STUFF`

This code will list all table's names and their columns in a comma delimited list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbls.name AS TableName,
                STUFF(
                    (
                     SELECT ', ' + cols.name
                     FROM sys.columns AS cols
                     WHERE cols.object_id  = tbls.object_id
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                     ), 1, 2, '')  AS ColumnList
FROM sys.tables AS tbls
```